# Last opened / edited / visited files in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a way to get the last 10 opened / edited / visited files in Sublime Text 2 (as data for a python module)?

Comment: Under File > Open Recent you'll find the last 8 or 9 files you had opened.

Comment: Right but i need as a python method for a ST2 plugin

Comment: Where in the question are you asking for that? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **edited or visited files** I use *Goto Anything* feature (by default `ctrl+p` on Win). The panel appears and files are sorted according to your recent activity. Of course you can filter there (just to type only part of the file name is enough). Is it what you are looking for?

In case of already **closed files** I use very handy [GoToRecent plugin](https://github.com/pomeh/dotfiles/tree/master/Sublime%20Text%202/Packages/GotoRecent). Surely it is worth a try! Default keybindings can be remapped (e.g. for `ctrl+e` add the following to the array in your user key bindings file):

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+e"], "command": "goto_recent" }
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a lot... I wanted to write this same plugin actually :-)

Comment: My pleasure. Surely better than reinventing the wheel... :-)